# Communication between objects in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes A and B which are defines as follows:

```
class A
{
    public:
    void *connector;
};

class B
{
    public:
    void *connector1;
    void *connector2;
};
```

To start, let us assume that I create three objects C1, C2 and C3 based on these classes,

```
A C1;
B C2;
A C3;
```

And I use the following code to connect them

```
C1.connector = &C2;
C2.connector1 = &C1;
C2.connector2 = &C3;
C3.connector = &C2;
```

So at the moment I have this:  C1 <-> C2 <-> C3 (first example).

Important: The reason I am using void pointers inside all the classes is because I cannot predict right from the start how the objects will connect. For example,the answer to this question should be valid if I create a fourth object and make these connections (C1 and C2 the same as before):

```
B C3;    
A C4;

C1.connector = &C2;
C2.connector1 = &C1;
C2.connector2 = &C3;
C3.connector1 = &C2;
C3.connector2 = &C4;
C4.connector = &C3;
```

Which corresponds to this C1 <-> C2 <-> C3 <-> C4 (second example).

I tried and searched everywhere for a simple solution to implement communication between these objects. There are even several questions with the same name but I could not find a similarity between what was asked and respective answers to the problem I am trying to solve. Maybe because I am not approaching this correctly right from the start. Anyway, by communication I mean a simple way that C2 can call a method in C1 and vice versa.

1) I tried to do it with templates but could not figure out how to do it. All classes would be templates and that seamed really contrived and complicated (hard to read, maintain and implement).

2) I tried to use casting of pointers but since I don't know right form the start to which class they connect I could not do it.

Important: Although I cannot warranty the connections I can live very well with the fact that, for example, an object of class B knows exactly the name of the method it will execute in the object connected to its connectors.

To make it clear, let us assume that we introduce a method

```
int get_value();
```

in both class A and class B (but the implementation is different in each class). So, in the second example above, C2 may call it on C1 and C3 may call this method on C2. But note that C2 and C3 are objects of the same class.

Ok, now that I explained my problem, I would like to ask for a simple solution for the communication in this problem. For example, a working piece of code that implements the communication between C2 and C1 but also between C3 and C2 (see example 2 above).

To be specific I think an example in which object C2/C3 can call the get_value method in C1/C2, such that C2/C3 can store the value in a private/public variable would be perfect.

I realize that the way I am trying to implement this may not be the best and answers that solve the problem on a different approach are also welcome. But if possible please show me some code and a little explanation because my main target and expertise is not the programming skills.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What you´re searching aren´t templates, but inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried so many things that I forgot to tell that I tried that too. I could not do it. My approach was to use a class called interface which would be the parent of class A and B above. however, I could not implement bidirectional communication and I would like a simple solution that avoids extra class (interface), if possible. I am sure inheritance can do a better job that I did and I am very interested in an answer in that direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, void* isn't the way to go.

One alternative approach could be to use inhertiance:

```
class OBJ 
{
public:  
    virtual string getValue()=0; 
};

class A : public OBJ 
{
public:
    OBJ *connector;
    string getValue();
};

class B : public OBJ
{
public:
    OBJ *connector1;
    OBJ *connector2;
    string getValue();
};
```

The objects could then easily "communicate" refering to the common members of the base OBJ class.

```
C1.connector->getValue(); 
C1.connector->connector2->getValue();
```

Comment: Works great. Just had to change string for int and create the getValue methods. Very simple. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to solve this problem is to define an *interface* class that describes the communication - the *functions* that can be performed:

```
// create an interface to communicate with
struct connected
{
    virtual ~connected() {} // must have virtual dtor

    virtual int get_value() = 0; // pure virtual functions
};

class A
: public connected // implement the connected interface
{
    int value;

public:
    A(int value = 0): value(value) {}

    // implement the connected interface
    int get_value() override { return value; }

    connected* connector = nullptr;
};

class B
: public connected // implement the connected interface
{
    int value;

public:
    B(int value = 0): value(value) {}

    // implement the connected interface
    int get_value() override { return value; }

    connected* connector1 = nullptr;
    connected* connector2 = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    A C1;
    B C2;
    A C3;

    C1.connector = &C2;
    C2.connector1 = &C1;
    C2.connector2 = &C3;
    C3.connector = &C2;

    C2.connector1->get_value(); // use the connected interface
}
```

This works because both `A` and `B` are *also* of type `connected` so they only need to care about the fact that they have pointers to other `connected` types and they don't need to care if they are `A` or `B`.

Comment: Can you point me a link or explain me a place where I can understand what this line does -> B(int value = 0): value(value) {}. I tried to find it in some c++ websites but they only cover the basics I guess. Also, the line with the "override" asks for -std=c++11 (its a warning). Why override is important here? For example, Christophe answer deals without it. If not asking to much, can you comment a little?

Comment: About the override: It´s new in C++11, and apparently your compiler isn´t in C++11 mode by default. `override` doesn´t really change how the code works, but it tells the compiler to check if there is a method with same name etc. in the parent too, and to treat it as error if this parent method is missing.

Comment: @deviantfan thanks for sharing your knowledge, but I lost my self in the part "calls a constructor from its parent class". What is the parent class of class B? Is it the connected class? But I see no method there called value. But if I change it to get_value I get error.

Comment: @Galik As you can see i am trying a lot to understand you answer but my c++ knowledge is not enough :) I am writing this to let you know that i think your answer is very good (maybe the best one), I will do my best to understand it! But to be honest I already solved my problem with the answer of Christophe and it was fast although he used a string in place of int. So I will mark his as the best answer for a beginner like me :) but thanks a lot for sharing your quality knowledge and I will try to do my best  to get it anyway because I am curious. I gave it +1 already!

Comment: @Blue Woah, I misread. Forget the constructor part. Corrected: 
`B(int value = 0): value(value) {}` is a constructor for the class B, with an parameter `int value`, which has a default value 0 if nothing is passed. Additionally, the class variable "value" is initialized with the value of the parameter "value", like writing `this->value = value;` (this many values are confusing...). It´s a special kind of syntax, a "initializer list"

Comment: @deviantfan now I got it! thanks for comments and hint "initalizer list" I will study it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact needs, but maybe you shall read the [observer pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3) it may help you. Or if you can maybe you can try to use `Qt` it has a nice siganl-slot mechanism.

Comment: It does not answer to my specific question, which was my main concern here, but seems to be very important topic which I was not aware. Thanks for the link.